# How to read a paragraph in natural language processing GATE

Tags: java, nlp, gate

I am using GATE tool for natural language processing.. i am using java code to read lines from the sentence and get the keywords.. what modification has to be done in creole xml to read complete paragraph..

Comment: Post your `java` code please, it will be easier to answer your question then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
doc.getNamedAnnotationSets().get("Original markups")
```

If it doesn't give any results, you can use the method `annotateParagraphs()` of the class 
 `gate.corpora.TextualDocumentFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do u mean, but if you use ANNIE you can put each paragraph in a separate tag. 
I used standAloneAnnie.java

> http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/StandAloneAnnie.java

If user enters

> ```
> What is your name, ,some text sometext
>
> Sometext sometext sometext
> ```

The result will be

```
<paragraph>What is your name, ,some text sometext</paragraph>

<paragraph>Sometext sometext sometext</paragraph>
```

You cane get more tags like, Person, Location, Sentence or Token for each word.

If user enters for example

> Where To Dine In Kuala Lumpur. Helton Hotel

The result will be an xml file that contains

```
<paragraph>
        <Sentence>
        <Token>Where</Token>
        <Token>To</Token>
        <Token>
        <Unknown>Dine</Unknown>
        </Token>
        <Token>In</Token>
        <Lookup>
        <Location>
        <Token>Kuala</Token>
        <Token>
        <Lookup>Lumpur</Lookup>
        </Token>
        </Location>
        </Lookup>
        <Token>
        <Split>.</Split>
        </Token>
        </Sentence>

        <Sentence>
        <Organization>
        <Token>Helton</Token>
        <Token>
        <Lookup>
        <Lookup>Hotel</Lookup>
        </Lookup>
        </Token>
        </Organization>
        </Sentence>

     </paragraph>
```

I am currently trying to get synonyms but unable to do so :( 
I want the result to include other options like for the above sentence, i want to result to have 
Dine -> Dinner, Food, Eat, Restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Initialize gate
2. Create gate controller (defaults with ANNIE)
3. Create corpus, set corpus to controller, create gate document (gateDoc), add to corpus
4. controller.execute();
5. following code

   ```
           FeatureMap features = gateDoc.getFeatures();
           String originalContent = (String)
        features.get(GateConstants.ORIGINAL_DOCUMENT_CONTENT_FEATURE_NAME);
           int length = originalContent.length();

           TextualDocumentFormat tdf = new TextualDocumentFormat();
               try {
                   tdf.annotateParagraphs(gateDoc,0, length,null);


               } catch (DocumentFormatException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           AnnotationSet paragraphs = gateDoc.getAnnotations().get("paragraph");

           Iterator it = paragraphs.iterator();
           Annotation currAnnot;
           SortedAnnotationList sortedParagraphs = new SortedAnnotationList();

           while (it.hasNext()) {
               currAnnot = (Annotation) it.next();
               sortedParagraphs.addSortedExclusive(currAnnot);
           } // while

           StringBuffer editableContent = new StringBuffer(originalContent);


               System.out.println("Number of Paragraphs -  "+paragraphs.size());

               for(Annotation paragraph:paragraphs){
                   long start = paragraph.getStartNode().getOffset().longValue();
                   long end = paragraph.getEndNode().getOffset().longValue();

                   String paraText=editableContent.substring((int) start, (int) end);
                   System.out.println(paraText);
               }
   ```